# Counting blanks, tabs and new line

Tags: c, character

I am new to C language, can someone help in identifying what am I doing wrong in implementing a program to count blanks, tabs, and newlines.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//Write a program to count blanks, tabs, and newlines.
int main(){
    char str[100];
    printf("Enter the text");
    scanf("%s",&str);
    int space=0;
    int tabs=0;
    int newLine=0;
    int i=0;
    while(str[i]!='\0'){
        if (str[i] == ' ')
            space++;
        if (str[i] == '\t')
            tabs++;
        if (str[i] == '\n')
            newLine++;
        i++;

    }

    printf("space:%d\ntabs:%d\nnew line:%d",space,tabs,newLine);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what if I want to get input from console instead of file? @xing

Comment: can I use getchar(). If yes, then how? because I have tried it but it is not giving the correct output

Comment: thanks it helped@xing

Comment: @xing - If `ch` should be an `int` for use with `getchar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way of checking this is to compare ascii values. C considers all characters are in ascii and that's that as far as C is concerned. So instead of comparing space to whitespace, compare it to 0x20 (the hex code of the ascii space character). Do likewise for the other comparisons and it should be a good bit better.

Don't be afraid to put in print statements to the terminal about the result of a comparison. For example print the character that is being checked vs what it is being checked against and also the result. This will help you to debug what is actually going on here. Don't forget to remove those print statements when you are finished.

PS here is the link to the ascii table.
http://www.asciitable.com

Comment: I think it is not a good idea to compare codes because in this case the program can not be used in systems where is used for example the EBCDIC  table.

Comment: Mostly I would agree but C is an ISO standard which means if you are using C then it uses ascii. There are variations because ascii is limiting but then it's not actual C just very like C. Now this doesn't make my solution any more right....it makes it less portable and worse best practice.

Comment: Why do you think that if C confirms to the ISO Standard then it follows that the all systems where the Standard C is implemented  uses the ASCII table? For example IBM mainframes use the EBCDIC table.

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf` function as it is used in your program is not safe and does not allow to count white spaces.

---

Note. Take into account that instead of

```
scanf("%s",&str);
          ^^^
```

it will be correct to write

```
scanf("%s",str);
          ^^^
```

And according to the C Standard function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

---

It is better to use the function `fgetc`

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int space = 0;
    unsigned int tabs = 0;
    unsigned int newLine = 0;

    printf( "Enter the text: " );

    int c;

    while ( ( c = fgetc( stdin) )  != EOF )
    {
        switch ( c )
        {
        case ' ':
            ++space;
            break;

        case '\t':
            ++tabs;
            break;

        case '\n':
            ++newLine;
            break;
        }
    }

    printf( "\nspace: %u\ntabs: %u\nnew line: %u\n", space, tabs, newLine );

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter a text like this

```
Hi, Marco Roberts 
Welcome to SO
```

then the program output will look like

```
space: 4
tabs: 0
new line: 2
```

Use Ctrl + z or Ctrl + d (depending on the used system) to interrupt the input.

Another approach can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   100

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int space = 0;
    unsigned int tabs = 0;
    unsigned int newLine = 0;

    printf( "Enter the text: " );

    char str[N];

    while ( fgets( str, sizeof( str ), stdin ) )
    {
        for ( const char *p = str; *p; ++p )
        {
            switch ( *p )
            {
            case ' ':
                ++space;
                break;

            case '\t':
                ++tabs;
                break;

            case '\n':
                ++newLine;
                break;
            }
        }           
    }

    printf( "\nspace: %u\ntabs: %u\nnew line: %u\n", space, tabs, newLine );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `fgets` instead of `scanf` if you want to do a console input (as said @xing in the comments). So we shall have :

```
#define SIZE_MAX 255

int main() {
    char str[SIZE_MAX];
    int i;
    int space;
    int tabs;

    printf("Enter the text : ");
    fgets(str, SIZE_MAX, stdin);    //stdin if it is a console input
    // Careful, if the input length is shorter than the SIZE_MAX (here 255),
    // Then a '\n' will be added at the end of your string. To counter it :
    if(strchr(str, '\n') != 0) {    //checks if there is a '\n'
        str[strlen(str)-1] = '\0';  //changes it to a '\0' (end of string)
    }

    //For the verifications, you can do that :
    for(i=0 ; i < strlen(str) ; i++) {
        if (str[i] == ' ') {
            space++;
        }
        if (str[i] == '\t') {
            tabs++;
        }
    }
    printf( "\nspace : %d\ntabs: %d\n", space, tabs);

    //NB : There will be no newLine because it is a console input.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @nsonore How to count in this case the new line characters?:)

Comment: Well, there will be no new line to count. When the user press enter it validates the input. As far as I know, you cannot add '\n' when you're using a console input.
However, if it is a file that you want to read, well fgets will read until the next new line, so you just have to create a counter for it.